# How to bind a child of an object / array dynamically to an element

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

Let's say, we have an element with a simple **two-way** binding to a sub property:

```
<x-element data="{{model.partOfData1}}"></x-element>
```

Is it possible to dynamically change the Part `partOfData1`? What I would love to do is something like this:

```
<x-element data="{{model[whichPartOfData]}}"></x-element>
```

While `whichPartOfData` would be a pointer to an array in the `model`. I have so many use cases for this but struggling to find a solution. What would be the best way to archive this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a computed binding, which takes the model and the property key as separate parameters:

```
<x-element data="[[getData(model, propertyName)]]"
           on-data-changed="updateModel"></x-element>

Polymer({
  is: 'x-element',
  getData: function(model, key) {
    return model[key];
  },
  updateModel: function(ev) {
    this.model[this.propertyName] = ev.detail.value;
  }
});
```

If it's a common case, you could extract the `getData` function to a [behaviour](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/behaviors).

To achieve two-way binding you would have to manually listen to change of the `data` property. After all data-binding is mostly events and listeners. I realize though that at this point the solution is kind of cumbersome.

Comment: Thanks! :) I tried that, but I'm searching for a solution with two-way binding. (I added this to the question. Sorry.)

Comment: See updated answer. There definitely is a better way though.